# How to use nested css class?

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

I am finding difficulties to write the correct CSS style in order to change a particular style. Currently using `vuetify` framework for front-end. Below is the inspect code from chrome.

```
<div class="flex lg10-custom">
  <div class="d-flex pt-0 mt-0 v-card v-card--flat v-sheet theme--light rounded-0">
    <div class="v-image v-responsive grey lighten-2 theme--light">
      <div class="v-responsive__sizer" style="padding-bottom: 100%;"></div>
      <div class="v-image__image v-image__image--contain"></div>
      <!---->
      <div class="v-responsive__content" style="width: 956px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, now I want to change the property of `padding-bottom: 100%` to `padding-bottom: 50%` and below is the code which I have written to change the CSS property.

`.lg10-custom > .d-flex > .v-image > .v-responsive__sizer{ padding-bottom: 50%;}`

It seems like the way I have set the rule isn't working, Please guide me on how to set proper css rule. Thanks!!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Listen to Dipak. View the element in the devtools inspector and you'll see that you're css is being overridden by something. You're over-qualifying you're selector.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Fabrizio and @Dan. I am able to override the CSS rule by adding
`.lg10-custom > .d-flex > .v-image > .v-responsive__sizer{ padding-bottom: 50% !important;}`